# ASP.Net C# MVC create exception to a global route

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I am writing a URL Shortener application.

When someone enters root.com/whatever, they are redirected to a configured URL.

I managed to create a global route which will catch the paths after the root ("whatever" above) and execute the corresponding redirection successfully.

**My problem and question is this:
The admin interface is at root.com/admin and when I try to access that, I get the global controller. How do I make an exception to the global controller for "admin"?**

Here is what I have in my route config right now:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Admin",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Global",
    url: "{suffix}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", suffix = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

For the first route, I also tried:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Admin",
    url: "admin/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

And I also tried putting it second in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will help you, but take a look at this stack overflow posting: [ASP.Net MVC: Routing issue which throwing exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50581204/asp-net-mvc-routing-issue-which-throwing-exception)
This person reduced the more specific route and it worked for him.

Comment: You are very welcome. Was it as shown in the other example?

Comment: Yes, very similar.